# Asteroids not showing when randomRestart is set to (550,650)?

Tags: processing

```java
class Sprite {
  float x;
  float y;
  float dx;
  float dy; 
}

Sprite player= new Sprite();

class Asteroids extends Sprite {
  float speedmultiplier;
  float speedupposition;
  color asteroidcolor;
  color hitcolor;
  String state; // "entering", "moving", "speed up"
```

When I set the randomRestart to anything starting beyond 500 (size of the screen), the asteroids stop animation in completely. There is also a x= random(550,650) within the update function in the "restart" state, and a roix.x= random(550,650) below that as well.  Could these be affecting the randomRestart?

Another side question is, how would I be able to input hit-detection with the asteroids so that the player loses a life?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```java
  void randomRestart(){
    x= random(550,650);
    y= random(50,550);
    speedmultiplier= random(1.10,1.5);
    dx= random(1.5,2.5);
    dy= 0;
    speedupposition= random(300,450);
    asteroidcolor= color(50,40,18);
    hitcolor= color(256, 0,0);   

    state = "entering";    
  }

  void render(){
    pushMatrix();
    if(state.equals("entering")){
      //translate(x,y);
      fill(asteroidcolor);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x,y,50,50);
    }
    else if(state.equals("speed up")){
      //translate(x,y);
      fill(asteroidcolor);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x,y,50,50);
    }

    else if(state.equals("hit")){
      //translate(x,y);
      fill(hitcolor);
      noStroke();
      ellipse(x,y,50,50);
    }
    else if (state.equals("restart")){
       translate(x,y); 
       fill(asteroidcolor);
       noStroke();
       ellipse(x,y,50,50);
    }

    popMatrix();
  }

  void update(){
  if (state.equals("entering")){
    x += -dx;
    if (state.equals("speed up")){
  x += -dx * speedmultiplier;
  }
  }
    if (x < 0 || x > width){
      state ="restart";
      randomRestart();    
      }

     else if (state.equals("restart")){
      x += dx;
       if (x < -50 || x >width){
      state = "entering";
      x= random(550,650);
      dx = -dx;
      randomRestart();
      }
  }
}


Asteroids randomAsteroids(){
  Asteroids roid = new Asteroids();
    roid.x= random(550,650);
    roid.y= random(50,550);
    roid.speedmultiplier= random(1.10,2.0);
    roid.dx= random(1.5,3.0);
    roid.dy= 0;
    roid.speedupposition= random(300,450);
    roid.asteroidcolor= color(50,40,18);
    roid.asteroidcolor= color(50,50,50);
    roid.hitcolor= color(256, 0,0);  
    return roid;
}

int NUM_ROIDS= 10;
ArrayList<Asteroids> roidsList;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  player.x = 50;
  player.y= 250;
  player.dx=0;
  player.dy=20.5; 

  roidsList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();

  int i = 0;
  while (i<8){
   Asteroids a = new Asteroids();
   a.randomRestart();
    roidsList.add(a);
    ++i;
  }
}


void draw(){
  background(255);
  fill(0,0,0);
  noStroke();
  rect(player.x,player.y,10,30);
  player.x += player.dx;

  for (Asteroids b : roidsList){
    b.render();
    b.update();
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  if (key =='w'){
  player.y += -player.dy;
  }
  if (key =='s'){
  player.y += player.dy;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code ? Currently it's not easy to run your code

Answer (score 0):

Check out this section of your code:

```
if (x < 0 || x > width){
   state ="restart";
   randomRestart();    
}
```

What happens if in your `randomRestart()` method, you make `x` more than `width`?

This if statement will always be triggered, so you'll restart your asteroid again, putting it outside the bounds of the screen, which triggers this if statement again, which restarts it, which... So you never give your asteroids a chance to get to the screen.

Instead, you might want to give your asteroids some room off-screen:

```
if (x < -100 || x > width + 100){
   state ="restart";
   randomRestart();    
}
```

Collision detection is a pretty huge topic, and you should probably try something and ask about it in a separate question. Don't forget to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on collision detection in Processing available [here](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/intermediateConcepts/collisionDetection).